# Voiceover - Overriding a UILabel's accessibilityLabel app-wide

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

I work on an education app for teachers.  In the US, we have a pseudo-grade named Pre-Kindergarten (sometimes still called Preschool).  It is commonly written as "PreK" with a pronunciation of "PreeKay".  This app displays grade names on many screens.  The data source is "PreK" for this grade, which is the correct text to display.

VoiceOver reads "PreK" as if it were a word, "prek".  While I'm sure VoiceOver users will know what this means, I'd like to get it right.

I know I can set the accessibilityLabel to "PreeKay" on an individual basis, and that works.  I would like to make this work app-wide, as cleanly as possible.

The option I'm considering is a custom UILabel to use whenever grade names are displayed, with code like this:

```
class GradeLabel: UILabel {
    override var text: String? {
        didSet {
            super.text = text
            guard let thisText = text?.uppercased() else { return }
            // The same label is sometimes used for other text, so I don't want to replace all
            //  occurrences of "PREK" should that be a legitimate substring
            //  NLTokenizer is probably a more correct approach for this.
            if thisText == "PREK" || thisText.starts(with: "PREK ") || thisText.contains(" PREK ") {
                accessibilityLabel = thisText.replacingOccurrences(of: "PREK", with: "PREEKAY")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not aware of such a thing, but I'm wondering if there's an app-wide "automatic VoiceOver translator" for custom words, along the lines of the built-in localization tools.

If such an "automatic VoiceOver translator" doesn't exist, I'm looking for feedback on my approach above.  <s>Overriding drawRect feels heavy-handed to me - but was the only "drop in replacement" method I came up with.</s>  Thank you to @matt for inspiring something better than drawRect!

Answer (score 0):

What you're proposing to do is a really bad idea. Don't read the presentation of the label (its `text`) and misuse it as *data*. The time to set this information is the time when you originally *set* the `text` of the label in the first place. You must be doing that somewhere; find *that* code and modify it so that at the same time you set the `text` to `"PreK"` you also set the accessibility label to "PreeKay".

(We have a very similar situation in our app; we often use a label "Qty" that must be read aloud as "Quantity". So every place in the app that *does* set a label's text to "Qty" must also set its accessibility label to "Quantity". When we realized that we had this issue, it only took a few minutes to find all the places where where we were doing this, and fix them.)

---

If you are going to go with the UILabel subclass solution instead, the place to do an override is the `text` property. You can put a setter observer on that and respond as you see fit. That's a lot cleaner than involving the `draw` method which is totally irrelevant.

Comment: I do see your point, although I don't think it's quite that bad.  This is essentially what VoiceOver does at runtime if no accessibilityLabel is explicitly set.  I find making one change centrally for a purpose cleaner than adding code everywhere (roughly 40 occurrences) and hoping future changes do the right thing too.  If I can do so without reading the text as data all the better.

Comment: What I'm saying that what needs to be "central" is the code that sets the label text. You should not be using hard-coded literal label text strings in any case (everything should be coming from a centralized repository of localized strings) so it's really easy to bottleneck this. — Anyway, you asked for feedback and I gave you some.

Comment: I do appreciate the feedback - thank you.  Most of the grade labels come from server-provided JSON as the string to display for the grade or class in question.  Sometimes it's translated (centrally) from a gradeId, using a server-provided JSON translation table.  The "PreK" literal string doesn't exist in the app, other than in test code.  I handle other translations the way you suggest; this is somewhat omnipresent throughout the app thus considering a different approach.

Comment: Well I think it would be better to have a UILabel subclass that overrides the `text` property with a setter observer than to involve `draw` wrongly as you are suggesting. That's just nuts.

Comment: _That_ is exactly what I was looking for - thank you!  I started this by trying to override UILabel's text `property` to add a `didSet`.  I got the `Cannot override with a stored property` error, and then went to my `draw` method (which I didn't like, as noted in the question).  Your comment caused me to dig deeper into Swift, and found a way to do exactly that.  Just something I hadn't learned about Swift yet.  I'll update the question with the new code, which I agree is much cleaner in concept.

Comment: Cool, I'll add my remarks to my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that if you change the "accessible name", whether through `accessibilityLabel` or another property, that not only does that affect what VoiceOver says (which is what you want) but it also affects Braille devices (which is what you don't want).  A Braille user would read "PreeKay".  They would never see "PreK".  That *might* be ok but could be confusing.

It's unfortunate that VoiceOver doesn't behave like other screen readers such as NVDA or JAWS that will honor the case of letters and treat a camel or mixed case word as multiple works.  That is, NVDA and JAWS will already say "PreK" as "PreeKay" because it sees the "Pre" separate from the "K" because they're uppercased.

While this isn't an ideal solution because every user would have to do this, VoiceOver users have control over how VoiceOver announces things.  They can go into Settings > Accessibility > VoiceOver > Speech > Pronunciations and add any words/phrases they want and give phonetic pronunciations, either by spelling the word how they want it pronounced or recording how they want it announced (which in turn translates it into a phonetic pronunciation where you can choose which one sounds closest to what you want, so it still uses VoiceOver's voice and not your voice.)

[image: screenshot of voiceover pronunciation setting]

Comment: That's excellent info, thank you.  I'm very familiar with how VoiceOver works, but (other than seeing demos) not very familiar with Braille devices on iOS.  It's very possible users of this app might set up such a pronunciation replacement, as a common industry term.  I'll also file a radar to speak the word as it should, due to the capitalization.